# Bind IList to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties

I created my own Custom control with its own `DependencyProperty`  `ItemsSource` It dynamically creates buttons based on the amount of items supplied in a bound list. When creating the XAML I should be able to bind a list to my custom control by declaring

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfData}".
```

I can't seem to get it display the buttons or show, is the data not binding to the list properly?

---

```
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button0States", Name = "Button0Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button0States", Name = "Button0NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button1States", Name = "Button1Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button1States", Name = "Button1NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button2States", Name = "Button2Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button2States", Name = "Button2NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button3States", Name = "Button3Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button3States", Name = "Button3NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button4States", Name = "Button4Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button4States", Name = "Button4NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button5States", Name = "Button5Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button5States", Name = "Button5NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button6States", Name = "Button6Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button6States", Name = "Button6NotVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button7States", Name = "Button7Visible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "Button7States", Name = "Button7NotVisible")]
         [TemplatePart(Name = "btn0", Type = typeof(Control))]
         [TemplatePart(Name = "btn7", Type = typeof(Control))]
         [TemplatePart(Name = "btnMore", Type = typeof(Control))]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "MoreButtonStates", Name = "MoreButtonVisible")]
         [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "MoreButtonStates", Name = "MoreButtonNotVisible")]
         public class FourByTwoGrid : Control
         {



        public FourByTwoGrid()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(FourByTwoGrid);

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(FourByTwoGrid_Loaded); 
            this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(FourByTwoGrid_GotFocus);
        }

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get {  return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IList; }
            set { Logger.Log("Value set"); SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the ItemsSource dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemsSource",
                typeof(IList),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// ItemsSourceProperty property changed handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">FourByTwoGrid that changed its ItemsSource.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FourByTwoGrid source = d as FourByTwoGrid;          

            if (source != null)
            {
                source.AttemptToBuildGridUi();
            }
        }

   #region public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets an ItemTemplate to be used in the buttons. 
        /// </summary>
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty) as DataTemplate; }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the ItemTemplate dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemTemplate",
                typeof(DataTemplate),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemTemplatePropertyChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// ItemTemplateProperty property changed handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">FourByTwoGrid that changed its ItemTemplate.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private static void OnItemTemplatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FourByTwoGrid source = d as FourByTwoGrid;

            if (source != null)
            {
                source.AttemptToBuildGridUi();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update the visual state of buttons based on whether or not an item exists. 
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateVisualState()
        {
            // set buttons to visible if there's a corresponding item
            var lastI = 0;

            if (ItemsSource != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ItemsSource.Count && i < 8; i++)
                {
                    lastI = i;
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Button" + i + "Visible", false);
                    Logger.Log("Visible" + i);
                }
                lastI++;
            }


            // set buttons to nto visible for all buttons that don't have a corresponding item
           for (int i = lastI; i < 8; i++)
            {
            }

            if (ShouldMoreButtonBeVisible)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MoreButtonVisible", false);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MoreButtonNotVisible", false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempt to populate the UI based on control properties. 
        /// </summary>
        private void AttemptToBuildGridUi()
        {
            UpdateVisualState();

            UpdateItemsSourceBindings();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It seems that the TemplateParent bindings aren't automatically updated. 
        /// We'll invoke Update on each of these. 
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateItemsSourceBindings()
        {

            if (ItemsSource == null)
                return;

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 0) && !ItemsSource[0].Equals(Item0))
                Item0 = ItemsSource[0];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 1) && !ItemsSource[1].Equals(Item1))
                Item1 = ItemsSource[1];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 2) && !ItemsSource[2].Equals(Item2))
                Item2 = ItemsSource[2];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 3) && !ItemsSource[3].Equals(Item3))
                Item3 = ItemsSource[3];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 4) && !ItemsSource[4].Equals(Item4))
                Item4 = ItemsSource[4];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 5) && !ItemsSource[5].Equals(Item5))
                Item5 = ItemsSource[5];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 6) && !ItemsSource[6].Equals(Item6))
                Item6 = ItemsSource[6];

            if ((ItemsSource.Count > 7) && !ItemsSource[7].Equals(Item7))
                Item7 = ItemsSource[7];

            Logger.Log("Layout updated");
            ItemsCountText = ItemsSource.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

#region public object Item0
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #0.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item0
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item0Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item0Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item0 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item0Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item0",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item0

        #region public object Item1
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #1.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item1
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item1Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item1Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item1 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item1",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item1

        #region public object Item2
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #2.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item2
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item2Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item2Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item2 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item2",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item2

        #region public object Item3
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #3.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item3
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item3Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item3Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item3 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item3Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item3",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item3

        #region public object Item4
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #4.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item4
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item4Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item4Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item4 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item4Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item4",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item4

        #region public object Item5
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #5.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item5
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item5Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item5Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item5 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item5Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item5",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item5

        #region public object Item6
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #6.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item6
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item6Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item6Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item6 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item6Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item6",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item6

        #region public object Item7
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets item #7.
        /// </summary>
        public object Item7
        {
            get { return GetValue(Item7Property) as object; }
            set { SetValue(Item7Property, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the Item7 dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Item7Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item7",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(FourByTwoGrid),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion public object Item7
```

---

EpisodeList is an IList in the SeriesViewModel class, I would like to bind that list to my EpisodeGrid control.

```
public class SeriesViewModel : CoreViewModel
{
     public IList episodeList = new ObservableCollection<Episode>
     {
         new Episode {image =""},

         new Episode {image =""},
         ......
     }


    public IList EpisodeList
    {
        get {return this.episodeList;}
        set
        {
            this.episodeList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EpisodeList");
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
<Core:CoreView
xmlns:Core="clr-namespace:AmebaTV_XBOXApplication.ViewModel"
x:Class="AmebaTV_XBOXApplication.UI.EpisodeGridView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:GridLayout="clr-namespace:AmebaTV_XBOXApplication.Controls.GridLayout"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:xbox="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xbox.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Xbox"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="720" d:DesignWidth="1280"
Title="EpisodeGridView Page">

<Core:CoreView.ViewModel>
    <Binding Path="SeriesViewModel" Source="{StaticResource viewModelLocator}"/>
</Core:CoreView.ViewModel>

<Core:CoreView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="button_template">
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" >
            <TextBlock Text="Button"/>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</Core:CoreView.Resources>

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Margin="0">         
    <GridLayout:FourByTwoGrid x:Name="fourbytwogrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeList}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource button_template}"/>

  </Grid>
</Core:CoreView>
```

What am I missing above? it compiles fine, but at runtime The EpisodeList does not bind.

Comment: Do you have an `EpisodeList` property on your viewmodel which wraps the `episodeList` field?

Comment: @nemesv , yes I do , I'll include it in the edit

Comment: What do you mean on "EpisodeList does not bind"? How do you use the `ItemsSource` DP in your `EpisodeGrid`?

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeList}"

Comment: EpisodeGrid is the custom UserControl, EpisodeList is the list of items for ItemSource.

Comment: Please post the xaml of your `EpisodeGrid`? Especially how do try to use the `ItemsSource` DP in your `EpisodeGrid`?

Comment: @nemesv Just posted the Xaml in the edits above.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Debug Output? What do you mean by 'not binding'?

Comment: @Erno No there are no errors in the debug output. When I say its not binding, I mean I provide it a list and it does bind to this data I provided in the list. . I will add more detail to the problem description.

Comment: I've added more detail and code to the description.

Comment: Does Episode implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: @Erno Yes it does through a super class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the code and it does appear to bind fine.

If you set a break-point in the OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged method, you can see that the DP ItemsSourceProperty is bound to the EpisodeList and that the call to get IList stored in the property ItemsSource has exactly the value we would expect to have.

What evidence suggests that the EpisodeList is not bound to ItemsSource?

If the problem is that the grid buttons are not displaying, I'm not sure you have shown any code for how you create the button controls, perhaps the issue is there and not in the binding.

Here is an example of a ControlTemplate I have written that manages the state you defined in your FourByTwoGrid class.  You can add the following in your XAML to reference it.

```
    <GridLayout:FourByTwoGrid x:Name="fourbytwogrid"
      ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeList}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource butemp}"
      Template="{StaticResource FourByTwoGridTemplate}" />
```

And here is the definition of the ControlTemplate.  Without this, your code has no way of knowing how to display the states you reference in your method UpdateVisualState().

Add this to your resource dictionary in your CoreView XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FourByTwoGridTemplate" TargetType="GridLayout:FourByTwoGrid">
        <Grid>
            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="Button0States">
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button0Visible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button0NotVisible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="Button1States">
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button1Visible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button1NotVisible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="Button2States">
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button2Visible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Button2NotVisible">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>

            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Button0" Content="0" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="Button1" Content="1" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="Button2" Content="2" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="Button3" Content="3" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="Button4" Content="4" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="Button5" Content="5" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Name="Button6" Content="6" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="Button7" Content="7" Visibility="Hidden" />
        </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: The buttons are created dynamically using AttemptToBuildGridUi() which calls UpdateVisualState() and UpdateItemsSourceBindings().

Comment: I bind each button to a template in the XAML : ItemTemplate="{StaticResource button_template}"

Comment: What do you mean the buttons are created dynamically? Can you post the code where you define your visual state transitions? I see the code where you build a string to map to a define TemplateVisualState attributes, can you post the code that defines those attributes. It is my opinion that the problem lies there and not in the binding between the EpisodeList and the ItemsSource.

Comment: Maybe Im misunderstanding what you are asking or I have missed a step. In the code above , please scroll down to the UpdateVisualState() function. It is there where the buttons are set to visible or not visible depending on the number of items in ItemsSource.

Comment: You are just setting the visual state, but the system doesn't know what the state "Button0Visible" should do.  You need to create a control template for that.

Comment: If it accomplished with this piece of code  <Core:CoreView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="button_template">
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" >
            <TextBlock Text="Button"/>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</Core:CoreView.Resources>

Comment: then :  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource button_template}"

Comment: There I create a template for the control.  Can you provide and example if this is incorrect?

Comment: That is fine, but that doesn't tell the system how to display the button, what to make visible/invisible, etc.  I have an example (it doesn't use the ItemTemplate) but maybe it will get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you , with a bit of tweaking this seem to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in the `ViewModel`.  You're attempting to bind `ItemsSource` to a property named "EpisodeList".  But the `RaisePropertyChanged` refers to the non-bound member "episodeList".

Comment: I changed it to EpisodeList,  still having the same issue.